# Filter apps of Cordova's Email Composer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I use this plugin: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/emailComposer/

This is my angular code:

```
$scope.report = function(){
    var CEO_EMAIL_ADDRESS = 'support@example.com';

    $cordovaEmailComposer.isAvailable().then(function() {
        $cordovaEmailComposer.open({
            to: CEO_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
            subject:  langTranslateService.getData('REPORT_A_PROBLEM'),
            body: '',
            isHtml: false
        });
    });
};
```

I need only the phone email will be opened or the option to choose from email applications only.

Why there is "bluetooth, dropbox..." in the options?

Can I change it..?

[image: popup options]

Answer (score 1):

According to the plugin specification found [here](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer#specify-email-app), you should be able to supply an `app` option to the `open` method to target a specific app for opening the email draft (at the time of writing Android only).

First an alias should be made for the desired app like so:

```
cordova.plugins.email.addAlias('outlook', 'com.microsoft.android.outlook');
```

This example creates an alias `outlook` for the Outlook app. The second parameter is the package name of the app, which I was able to find by installing a plugin like [Package Name Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gijoon.pkgnameviewer&hl=en).

You can validate if the app is available with the following overload of the [isAvailable](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer#determine-if-the-device-is-capable-to-send-emails) function:

```
cordova.plugins.email.isAvailable(
    'outlook', function (isAvailable, withScheme) {
        // isAvailable indicates if sending emails is available at all
        // withScheme is true if the desired app/scheme is available. When false the fallback of choosing an approriate app is applied
    }
);
```

Then you can supply this alias to the open method like in the example below:

```
$cordovaEmailComposer.open({
    app: 'outlook',
    to: CEO_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
    subject:  langTranslateService.getData('REPORT_A_PROBLEM'),
    body: '',
    isHtml: false
});
```

Now the draft should open in Outlook when available. Give it a try!